What to do with duplicate without answer in the Staging Ground?
When a Staging Ground question has been answered in another question already, it can be flagged as a duplicate. But what about questions that have been asked already without getting an answer? Normally, you'd just not do anything with it but with the Staging Ground, someone needs to decide on whether or not to approve the question.
Should duplicates of questions without answers be approved? Is there a point of having the same question twice with (probably) no answers on either of them?

I don't think we need to differ here on what's already being done. If the duplicate target has not been answered it doesn't really make any sense to close it as a duplicate.

The question is whether it makes sense to essentially create the same question twice.

Those two questions seem to ask about entirely different things. The one in SG wants to start/stop the recorder to create a record. The one already asked wants to modify an existing record when replaying it.

You could argue that the rule surrounding what makes a question a duplicate may need a revisit now that the staging ground is a thing to make it more sensible. But right now, a question is only a duplicate if there is an answer involved. If there is no such answer... not a duplicate. Because of that built-in leniency, the question is fit for the site. so I guess put it on the watch list and if it gets answered, dupe close the older question.

The two are not duplicate at all. In How do I start a DevTools user flow recording from a dynamic URL? the asker wants to record a sequence of events then re-play them but change the starting point. So, if the recording started at page A then went to B, the asker wants to be able to start from page Z and then the recording would progress to B. The SG question wants to use the recording programmatically. Doesn't need to be replayed differently.

Are we talking about situations where you recognize the SG question as a dupe of an unanswered already-published question? Or as a dupe of another SG question? Are we talking about the special case for dupes asked by the same author (which don't need to be answered to close as a duplicate)?

@KarlKnechtel I am talking about duplicates of already published questions that have no answer.

As said elsewhere - a duplicate is a signpost saying "your answer is over there". If a similar question was asked but never answered, it may be that this new question will be subtly different and attract an answer. Then the old may be closed as a duplicate of the new.

Nothing really, or rather, same current rules still apply? If the supposed "dupe" has not already been answered ,or isn't created by the same author, and all the other duplicate closure criteria have not been met, it doesn't seem to be a duplicate under the current regime. If the post is good enough to be published on its own merit in isolation, then it is good enough to publish. If it later becomes the "duplicate" because the existing post got answered then it can be closed, otherwise it could be answered and the "other" post becomes the duplicate.

You can't close a duplicate if the dup target doesn't have an accepted or upvoted answer, so there's no way to close it anyway and the usual rules apply.

Practically, the same thing we've doing with them in the main site. Letting both stand, and when one is answered, then we consider if that answer applies to the other question.
If you want, you can leave a link to the other question, it may be helpful later on.

I foresee a "problem"/mini abuse of the system: That the Answerer will post their Answer to both Questions instead of choosing the one with the best quality or most views (because chance to get Rep, always more Rep...!), and even if they only posted their Answer to the best quality Question, that some 1/Low-Rep User will quickly copy/port that Answer to the other Question before it gets closed as Dupe to try to "surf" for Rep on that original Answer.

To be honest, I think it isn't even likely that the dupe would be "discovered" when one of the question gets answered so it might not even lead to one of the questions being closed as a dupe of the other.
